# sample_wave on Python 3 Doesn't Create Speech Handler

Tags: houndify

One has to make a couple of adjustments to run the sample_wave.py example program on Python 3.  But having made them and having sent a .wav file to the Voice endpoint I get:

b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'b'e14\r\n{"Format":"SoundHoundVoiceSearchResult","FormatVersion":"1.0","Status":"Error","ErrorMessage":"Could not create speech handler because audio is not supported. (audio bytes received:

The audio bytes that followed the colon start with

\"52 49 46 46 62 27 24 5c 78 30 30 5c 78 30 30 5c 78 ...

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers, Scott

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the audio file isn't supported, most likely because you need a header.

You can read more about supported formats here.  https://www.houndify.com/docs#compressing-and-streaming-audio-formats

Best,
James